# Is there a way to make the Emacs minibuffer show up larger in the center of the window?

Tags: emacs

Basically, the minibuffer is small and at the bottom of the screen.

With a large monitor especially, this means I often need to lean forward to read it. It is also very long - this makes it slower to read. (no line breaks)

The minibuffer is sort like a launcher/error area - so it seems logical that it act more like some combination of quicksilver/growl.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the minibuffer taller by using the function `enlarge-window` or its keyboard shortcut <kbd>C-x ^</kbd>. See [is it possible to move the emacs minibuffer to the top of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050011/is-it-possible-to-move-the-emacs-minibuffer-to-the-top-of-the-screen) for some thoughts on how to move the minibuffer itself.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a standalone minibuffer frame. That saves real estate: no need for a minibuffer in each frame. And it also lets you configure the look and feel separately for the minibuffer.  I use a minibuffer frame that extends across my whole screen and is (by default) 2 lines high.  The minibuffer can hold any number of lines, BTW.

This is what I use, in case it helps:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/oneonone.el

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Dedicated_Minibuffer_Frame